# How to connect UITextView to a home made keyboard?

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextfield, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I  have a UITextView field meant to receive input from a keyboard.

But the standard keyboard not being adequate for my app, I built another one with the buttons and characters I need.

I would normally  make use of the UITextViewDelegate protocol and things would work.
But in this situation, how do I connect the UITextView field and my new keyboard?
Is there a "best way to do it"?

Thanks in advance for any relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your custom view as `inputView` of the `UITextView`.

// Edit: additional information:

Your custom keyboard will be a collection of buttons. You can add the same selector as target for all those buttons. Than your callback could be:

```
- (void) buttonTouched: (UIButton*) button
{
    myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString: button.text];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip. Searching on the net  for inputView and UITextView makes me think you definitely put me on the right track.
Though I still have a lot of work to do before I get my UITextView actually getting input from my custom keyboard. Since I have never done that before, there are a lot of details I do not know how to handle in the process. Like how do I deal with the key events on the custom keyboard and other things. It would be nice to have a small and clear sample, but that I did not find yet.

Comment: I can see the logic here about the IBAction. I presume what you call:
- (void) buttonTouched: (UIButton*) button;
is the same as what I call:
-(IBAction) kbdButtonHandle:(id)sender;
in my custom keyboard class. Tell me if I am wrong.
But how is declared myTextView in your example? Which I suppose points to the UITextView instance.
Because the keyboard instance does not know about the UITextView instance (again tell me if I am wrong);
I do not quite understand where the link is made.

Comment: You have to make it on your own. When you set the inputView (`myCustomKeyboard.inputView = myCustomKeyboard`), you could also set the textView in your keyboardClass. E.g.: `[myCustomKeyboard setTextView: theTextView];`

Comment: Thanks. I will try to find more info and experiment. I am not quite following this last comment, but maybe making my custom keyboard a subclass of UIView was already a mistake.

Comment: No its not a mistake. Just add a property to your keyboard class, where you can set a UITextView, which than will be used in your `kbdButtonHandle:`. Feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8646/discussion-between-michel-and-jaydee3)